# Create intermediate element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to invoke a creation of div with certain class just below the invoke button, how can I do that most efficiently with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method in the button's click handler

```
$(input_btn).click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="myclass">content</div>')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('<div />', {class:'myClass'}).insertAfter(this);
});
```

Comment: @Gandalf StormCrow: is seems `class` is a reserved word, it should be `'class':'myClass'`.